# Ui-sref and md-button. How it works?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

[Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/UROiwBX58lTKxshBARnI?p=preview)

Why menu item "Menu1" above the others if i add ui-sref ????

```
 <md-button  ui-sref="menu1" >Menu1</md-button>
 <md-button>Menu2</md-button>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using `ui-sref`, then you should enclose it with Anchor tag.

```
<md-button><a ui-sref="menu1">Menu1</a></md-button>
```

As Hooligancat says, here is the updated Code:

```
<a ui-sref="menu1" class="md-button">Menu1</a>
```

Hope it works

Comment: In angular-material 1.09 and angular 1.5.8 this solution removes the default hover effect, which is bad. Why is removing the default material design behaviour intended in the first place? -1.

Comment: But then you really have to click the text in the button to make the button perform some action. I had done this but I had to reverse my changes since you cannot expect a user to click the button right at the centre all the time, which could cause serious UI problems.

Answer (score 19):

It's actually better to *wrap* the button in the `a` tag. The problem with the recommended solution is that only the text acts as a link rather than the whole button, so I'd suggest;

```
<a ui-sref="menu1"><md-button>Menu1</md-button></a>
```

Comment: This one works perfect. The above solutions as @Stuart mentioned only act for the text rather than whole button.

Answer (score 3):

Better yet is to dispense with using two tags and specify 'md-button' as a class on the 'a' tag.

```
<a ui-sref="menu1" class="md-button">Menu1</a>
```

You can of course add any other material class tags too...

```
<a ui-sref="menu1" class="md-button md-raised md-primary">Menu1</a>
```