# ui-sref with a-tag inside md-button is clickable only on a-tag

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-material

I have to click directly on the hyperlink inside the md-button to activate the ui-state.

I would like to click on the md-button to acivate the ui-state.

How can I do this?

```
<md-button><a ui-sref="tests">Tests</a></md-button>
```

Comment: ummm  adjust the css? Or use `ng-click` or `$state.go()` on button

Comment: Yeah, @charlietfl is right. You don't have to place an `a` inside of the button, just enter the text inside and add the nav behavior with angular on the button.

Comment: I have to use the a-tag as workaround because without the vertical alignment of the md-button is broken. see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32435358/ui-sref-and-md-button-how-it-works